# How to multiply all columns of a dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to multiply all values less than 1 in a dataframe by 1000. 
Below is an example of a dataframe;
[image]

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If first column is not numeric use multiple all columns without first selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) by `1000` or `1` by condition with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abc'),
         'B':[4,-5,4],
         'C':[7,8,-9],
         'D':[7,1,0]})

df.iloc[:, 1:] *= np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:] < 1, 1000, 1)
print (df)
   A     B     C  D
0  a     4     7  7
1  b -5000     8  1
2  c     4 -9000  0
```

If first column is index multiple all columns by condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,-5,4],
         'C':[7,8,-9],
         'D':[7,1,0]}, index=list('abc'))

df[df < 1] *= 1000
#same like
#df[df < 1] = df[df < 1] * 1000
print (df)
      B     C  D
a     4     7  7
b -5000     8  1
c     4 -9000  0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for col in df.columns.tolist()
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x * 1000 if x < 1, axis=1)
```